# Why am I getting "is not a function" error for generateRequest Polymer iron-ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer

Uncaught TypeError: this.$.ajax.generateRequest is not a function Polymer.setajax @ assets-ajax.html:23 
        handler @ polymer.html:390
assets-ajax.html

```
<dom-module id="assets-pull">
<style>
</style>
<template>

    <button on-click="setajax">Click me</button>

    <iron-ajax
            id="ajax"
            url=""
            handle-as="json"
            on-response="hresponse"
            debounce-duration="300">
    </iron-ajax>

</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "assets-pull",
        setajax: function () {
            this.$.ajax.url = "http://mytesturl.com/assets_all";
            this.$.ajax.params = {"userId":"1"};
            this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
        },
        hresponse: function(request) {
            console.log(request.detail.response);
            console.log(this.$.ajax.lastResponse);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code works for me. Make sure iron-ajax element is installed and imported.

Example:

```html
<link rel="import" href="../components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
<dom-module id="assets-pull">
  ...
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Thanks.  That worked.  I thought if I included polymer in the calling page that would work...  But, as these are web components and should be self contained, it is making more sense.

Comment: So true!, the same issue in Polymer 3. We must be sure iron-ajax element is imported.